# Create a Public API from a Set of Classes in C#

Tags: c#, .net, assemblies, facade

I have a large collection of custom C# classes that roughly follow the MVC pattern that I reuse over and over to build GUI and command line PC applications with different groupings of functionality. For example there are classes for importing and exporting files, classes for manipulating data, classes for monitoring, utility classes, etc.

These classes are currently grouped into a set of assemblies. The higher-level assemblies reference lower-level assemblies, which in turn reference even lower-level assemblies.

All the classes are marked as public so when I build a PC application I can reference the appropriate assemblies and uses the classes in a modular fashion.

When I release a PC application I use a .NET obfuscator to merge the assemblies and the EXE into a single EXE so end users cannot see the APIs of all the classes and assemblies.

Now I would like to create a .NET assembly from my collection of classes that only exposes a specific, limited API and give it to end-users. I guess this is the facade design pattern.

For example I would like to take assemblies A and B and use classes from those, say A.Foo, A.Bar, A.Baz, B.Foobar, B.Bazbar, B.Bazfoo and create a new assembly, C, that has a single public class C.MyClass. Assembly C references assemblies A and B. End users can only see C.MyClass and they can't see or access A.xxx or B.xxx.

Is there a clean way of doing this that doesn't require drastic changes to my current collection of classes and assemblies (as they are already used in multiple other projects)?

Or is this something that is typically handed in the merging/obfuscation stage instead?

Thanks!

Comment: It's an odd predicament, have you considered "Add as link" in Visual Studio? You could have all of your files in one project and just add selected ones as links in other the thinned down projects. Unfortunately this smells like a maintenance headache regardless.

Comment: Thanks. Already doing that in VS. This is more about hiding public classes rather than referencing assemblies. Unless I am misunderstanding?